# calling a java program in a python script : Classpath Error

Tags: java, python, classpath, subprocess

i am running a python script, which is essentially about information retrieval. Since one execution of the script takes a very long time, i want to run parallel scripts. I am calling the java program using the following code in my script:

```
x='java -cp "lib/*:esalib.jar" clldsystem.esa.ESAAnalyzer %s %s' % (word1, word2)
args=shlex.split(x)
print args
p=subprocess.Popen(args)
p.wait()
```

It works fine. In order to not mix up the input files and temporary result files, i created a new folder within the folder which contains the script. I'm now trying to run a copy of the script from the new folder. I updated the code to:

```
x='java -cp "../lib/*:esalib.jar" ../clldsystem.esa.ESAAnalyzer %s %s' % (word1, word2)
args=shlex.split(x)
print args
p=subprocess.Popen(args)
p.wait()
```

But this gives an error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ...clldsystem.esa.ESAAnalyzer
```

How could i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are putting the `..` dots in the wrong place.

`clldsystem.esa.ESAAnalyzer` is the Java class that contains the `main()` method which is to be executed by `java`. `java` tries to find `clldsystem.esa.ESAAnalyzer` by looking through the classes which it loads from the jars specified in the classpath by `-cp`.

So try replacing

```
java -cp "../lib/*:esalib.jar" ../clldsystem.esa.ESAAnalyzer
```

with the following:

```
java -cp "../lib/*:../esalib.jar" clldsystem.esa.ESAAnalyzer
```